# Azure batch operations delete several blobs and tables

Tags: azure

I have a function that deletes every table & blob that belongs to the affected user.

```
        CloudTable uploadTable = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudUploadsTable();
        TableQuery<UploadEntity> uploadQuery = uploadTable.CreateQuery<UploadEntity>();
        List<UploadEntity> uploadEntity = (from e in uploadTable.ExecuteQuery(uploadQuery)
                                          where e.PartitionKey == "uploads" && e.UserName == User.Idendity.Name
                                          select e).ToList();

        foreach (UploadEntity uploadTableItem in uploadEntity)
        {
            //Delete table
            TableOperation retrieveOperationUploads = TableOperation.Retrieve<UploadEntity>("uploads", uploadTableItem.RowKey);
            TableResult retrievedResultUploads = uploadTable.Execute(retrieveOperationUploads);
            UploadEntity deleteEntityUploads = (UploadEntity)retrievedResultUploads.Result;
            TableOperation deleteOperationUploads = TableOperation.Delete(deleteEntityUploads);
            uploadTable.Execute(deleteOperationUploads);

            //Delete blob
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudBlobsContainer();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uploadTableItem.BlobName);
            blob.Delete();
        }
```

Each table got its own blob, so if the list contains 3 uploadentities, the 3 table and the 3 blobs will be deleted.

I heard you can use table batch operations for reduce cost and load. I tried it, but failed miserable. Anyone intrested in helping me:)?

Im guessing tablebatch operations are for tables only, so its a no go for blobs, right?

How would you add tablebatchoperations for this code? Do you see any other improvements that can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not very clear from your code as to what you're trying to do. Can you please explain what you're trying to accomplish. Also, please explain the following 1) `Each table got its own blob`. 2) `I heard you can use table batch operations for reduce cost and load. I tried it, but failed miserable`.

Comment: You're asking for... what? Guidance on improvements to your code? Guidance for adding batch operations? Those questions are too broad (and opinion-seeking). Regarding table batch operations: As @Gaurav asked: What, exactly, do you mean by *failed miserably*? What did you try? You're correct that batch operations are for tables and not blobs; they're limited to operations within a single partition, up to 100 entities (as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894038.aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to use batch operations but I didn't know how. Anyhow, I figured it out after some testing.

Improved code for deleting several entities:

```
        CloudTable uploadTable = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudUploadTable();
        TableQuery<UserUploadEntity> uploadQuery = uploadTable.CreateQuery<UserUploadEntity>();
        List<UserUploadEntity> uploadEntity = (from e in uploadTable.ExecuteQuery(uploadQuery)
                                               where e.PartitionKey == "useruploads" && e.MapName == currentUser
                                               select e).ToList();

        var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

        foreach (UserUploadEntity uploadTableItem in uploadEntity)
        {
            //Delete upload entities
            batchOperation.Delete(uploadTableItem);

            //Delete blobs
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudBlobContainer();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(uploadTableItem.BlobName);
            blob.Delete();
        }

        uploadTable.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
```

I am aware that batchoperations are limited to 100 but in my case its nothing to worry about.